# How to run a function in 'background'

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm parsing the last line of a continuously updating log file. If it matches, I want to return the match to a list and start another function using that data. I need to keep watching for new entries and parse them even while the new function continues.

I've been working this from a few different angles for about a week with varying success. I tried threading, but ran into issues getting the return value, I tried using a global var but couldn't get it working. I'm now trying asyncio, but having even more issues getting that to work.

```
def tail():
    global match_list
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

def thread():
    while True:
        tail()

def somefun(list):
    global match_list
    #do things here
    pass

def main():
    match_list = []
    f = open(r'file.txt')
    thread=threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(f,))
    thread.start()
    while True:
        if len(match_list) >= 1:
        somefun(match_list)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Wrote the above from memory..
I want tail() to return the line to a list that somefun() can use.
I'm having issues getting it to work, I will use threading or asyncio.. anything to get it running at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asyncio you might use two coroutines, one that reads from file, and the other that processes the file. Since they communicate using queue, they don't need the global variable. For example:

```
import os, asyncio

async def tail(f, queue):
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        await queue.put(line)

async def consume(queue):
    lines = []
    while True:
        next_line = await queue.get()
        lines.append(next_line)
        # it is not clear if you want somefun to receive the next
        # line or *all* lines, but it's easy to do either
        somefun(next_line)

def somefun(line):
    # do something with line
    print(f'line: {line!r}')

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        await asyncio.gather(tail(f, queue), consume(queue))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    # or, on Python older than 3.7:
    #asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

The beauty of an asyncio-based solution is that you can easily start an arbitrary number of such coroutines in parallel (e.g. you could start `gather(main1(), main2())` in an outer coroutine, and run that), and have them all share the same thread.

Comment: Edited your code to what I *think* is correct. In yours, when a newline came in it wouldn't account for it after starting somefun(). I'm still not sure how asyncio works but your example was a big help @user4815162342

Comment: @Scott In the meantime I've tested the code and fixed some typos, adding some output to `somefun` in the process. I haven't noticed it missing a newline, though. Does it still happen with the current version?

Comment: I'll try to explain a little better... I'm not sure how to test this properly since a time.wait will just freeze everything(I think). In my main program the functions inside main() take about a minute+ to complete.. its during this time that I need to monitor for new messages coming in. After somefun() does its job I need to remove the line from the list, and move on to the next one, or go back to waiting for a new one.

Comment: @Scott In this version you might not even need a "list" to remove from, because the queue serves that purpose. I've retained a list in case you need to send it to `somefun` for some other reasons - for example, in case `somefun` it needs access to all previous messages for whatever reason.

Comment: How would I go about actively checking the queue, to alter the behavior of `somefun` once it has started?`somefun` requires updates from the result of `tail` to decide how to proceed.

Comment: @Scott In that case maybe you don't need `somefun` as separate from `consume`? The logic of `somefun` could be moved to `consume`, which *can* (and does) receive updates from `tail` via the queue.

Comment: would I get the updated line simply by `next_line = await queue.get()` in a while loop as needed?

Comment: @Scott Of course! There is nothing magical about the current `consume` function (which consists exactly of such a `while` loop), you can restructure it however you want, and implement your logic right there if needed. (That is what I meant by "logic of `somefun` could be moved to `consume`" in the last comment.)

Answer (score -1):

with a few small fixes you almost run this :) (comments inside)

```
match_list  # should be at the module scope

def tail():
    # f = open(...) ???
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

def thread():
    for line in tail():
        match_list.append(line)  # append line
    print("thread DONE!")

def somefun(list):
    #do things here
    while match_list:
        line = match_list.pop(0)
        print(line)

def main():
    match_list = []
    f = open(r'file.txt')
    thread=threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(f,))
    thread.start()
    while True:
        if match_list:
            somefun(match_list)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # <-- don't burn the CPU :)
```